# Nilpotent minimal ideals are one sided minimal ideals

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be an Artinian ring. I am looking for some condition under which all nilpotent (two sided) minimal ideals of $R$ are both minimal left and minimal right ideals. Can anyone give some hint? Thanks!

Comment: It's interesting... do you have any more motivation or clues about the problem? Or previous work?

Comment: I was motivated by the quasi-Frobenius ring criterion provided by Nakayama: Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra with $k$ algebraically closed. Then $A$ is quasi-Frobenius if and only if $$\ell (r(I)) = I$$ and $$r(\ell (I)) = I$$ for every nilpotent minimal ideal and $$\ell (r( J(A))) = J(A), r(\ell (J(A))) = J(A) $$ where $J(A) $ is the Jacobson radical.  Here $\ell (\cdot )$ and $r(\cdot)$ are for left and right annihilator, respectively. Now if I know every nilpotent minimal ideal is actually one sided minimal ideal, then $r(I)$ and $\ell (I)$ are primitive then I have more info to proceed.

Comment: Great! Thanks for adding that. In fact, I am very interested in this area, and I will think about it.

Comment: I think you must be still assuming Artinianness in the criterion you mentioned. I am aware of a non Artinian dual ring that satisfies the conditions in the last comment. Do you happen to have a reference for the criterion? I'd like to take a look at it.

Comment: The reference is Theorem 8 in "On Frobeniusean Algebras. I"
Author(s): Tadasi Nakayama
Source: Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 40, No. 3 (Jul., 1939), pp. 611-633.    I think you are correct about the Artinianess assumption in the criterion.

Comment: Oh yes, I have definitely have that paper printed somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: At least we know this: for a finite dimensional $k$-algebra ($k$ algebraically closed) $A$, if $A$ is basic, then all minimal ideals are one sided minimal ideals.  This is because if $A$ is basic, so is $A \otimes A^{\mbox{op}}$.  However, this condition (i.e. being finite dimensional basic) might be too strong.